# How do I create an RHQ plugin?

Tags: java, jboss, metrics, rhq

I am trying to develop an rhq plugin for a service that requires metrics. The entire application uses an rhq-server. A new rhq-plugin is required, and I know that I have to create a new rhq-plugin.xml and deploy it as a jar to be used by the rhq-server. Is there a tutorial on creating rhq-plugins and adding metrics to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat published a [whitepaper](http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/Write_A_Plugin_WP_web.pdf) on how to create a RHQ-Plugin. That is probably a good starting point.

Other useful references

1. [Video](http://www.jboss.com/videos/jbosson/)
2. [Video2](http://vimeo.com/16171314)

Answer (score 2):

As a followup and enhancement to above whitepaper, this is now [available on GitHub](https://github.com/pilhuhn/misc_writing/tree/master/HowToWriteAnRhqPlugin) with a lot of additions and adjustments to newer RHQ versions.

The text provides a step-by-step example and also touches other areas of writing a plugin.

The [RHQ wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Home) provides additional information - also in its videos section.

If you need help, you can also join the RHQ team and community on irc at irc.freenode.net/#rhq